# How to pass time value from page.cs to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin

How to paas time value from page.cs to ViewModel.

timevalue is string like `"14h:15m"`

Here I'm trying...

Page.cs

`_model.StartTime = int.Parse(timevalue);`

```
ViewModel

public DateTime StartTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Today; 
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
public int Duration { get; set; } 
private TimeSpan[] _StartTimeValues { get; set; }
private int _StartTimeIndex = -1;
public int StartTime
{
    get { return _StartTime; }
    set
    {
        _StartTimeIndex = value;

        if (value >= 0)
        {
            StartTime =StartTime.Date.Add(_StartTimeValues[value]); 
            EndTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(Duration);                                   
        }       
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StartTime));                
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you also show your Page.xaml and Page.xaml.cs? Also, you should just call ```OnPropertyChanged()``` without the argument, because ```StartTimeDisp``` isn't defined anywhere in your sample code.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StartTime));  I have updated this. @ewerspej

Comment: Please clarify in your question what exactly you would like to achieve. Where is the time value coming from initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, please change the _StartTimeIndex's type to SpanTime, because the TimeDate.Add need a parameter type of SpanTime. Such as:

```
  string time = "12h45m";
  char[] hourandminute = new char[] { 'h', 'm' };
  string[] temp = time.Split(hourandminute);
  int hour = int.Parse(temp[0]);
  int minutes = int.Parse(temp[1]);
  TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(hour, minutes, 0);
```

Comment: In this line error is coming at [value] `StartTime = StartTime.Date.Add(_StartTimeValues[value]);`   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int' @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Try to use `StartTime = StartTime.Add(_StartTimeValues[value])`. @Raj

Comment: I'm using operator also, if (_StartTimeIndex < 0) `Operator `<` cannot be applied to operands of type 'TimeSpan' and 'int'` @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: What is the `if (_StartTimeIndex < 0)` used to do? @Raj

Comment: Just for input confirmation, it's check incomplete input items @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: But now I have commented this line and trying @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Now exception is coming `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' @LiyunZhang-MSFT
`

Comment: `_StartTimeIndex.Seconds` or `_StartTimeIndex.Minutes` or `_StartTimeIndex.Hours` can get the number of hours or minutes or seconds. @Raj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248533/discussion-between-liyun-zhang-msft-and-raj).

Comment: Please look this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74385076/how-can-i-achieve-this-in-my-code-datetime-starttime-startdatevalue-starttim) @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Can you show a value of the `StartTimeNames[0]`? @Raj

Comment: current value of  StartTimeNames[0] is 16H15M @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: Is every value same as `xxHxxM`? @Raj

Comment: Yes like this @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can check the answer I posted. @Raj