# How can i achieve this in my code DateTime StartTime = StartDateValue + StartTimeNames[0]?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to pass in `DateTime StartTime = StartDateValue + StartTimeNames[0],`
How I do this?

StartDateValue is a type of DateTime and StartTimeNames is string type and array of times.
StartTimeNames[0] string value is `13H15M`

StartTime value I would expect `11-11-2022 13:15:00`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
var status = await OrderStatusService.GetOrderStatus(new OrderStatus()
{
    StoreCode = s_code,
    StartTime = DateTime.Now.StartOfTheDay(),  //I want to replace this line with ( StartDateValue + StartTimeNames[0] )
    EndTime = DateTime.Now.EndOfTheDay()
});
```

```
public string[] StartTimeNames { get; set; }
```

```
private DateTime _StartDateValue;
public DateTime StartDateValue
{
    get
    {
        return _StartDateValue;
    }
    set
    {
        var sdv = _StartDateValue;

        Item.StartTime = value.Date + Item.StartTime.TimeOfDay;
        Item.EndTime = Item.StartTime.AddMinutes(Item.Duration);

        SetProperty(ref _StartDateValue, value);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StartDateDisp));   
        
        if (sdv != value)
        {
            FilterStartTimeValues();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide an exactly example of  string `StartTimeNames[0]` ?

Comment: StartTimeNames[0] string format like 16H30M @cg-zhou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to convert the string the a int value which is the total minutes. Such as:

```
    DateTime StartDateValue = DateTime.Now;
    string a = "12H23M";
    string[] strings = a.ToString().Split('H','M');
    int num = int.Parse(strings[0])*60 + int.Parse(strings[1]);
    DateTime StartTime = StartDateValue.AddMinutes(num);
```

Comment: It's works outside the method, but when i'm trying to pass this in `var status {StartTime = StartTime }`  so I'm getting null @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can use `StartTime = StartDateValue.AddMinutes(num);` instead of `StartTime = DateTime.Now.StartOfTheDay(), ` in your method. Needn't declare the `DateTime StartTime ` again. @Raj